# Space between two div tags

Tags: css, html, space

Hi I'm trying to set a space between two div tags but I don't know how to do it, I've been searching but I don't understand the examples that I've found

Here's the CSS code:

```
#logo{
    position:absolute;
    top:160px;
    left:65px;
}
#desc{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:290px;
    left:65px;
}
#desc_entry{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:5px;
    left:65px;
}
.pressed {
    color:#999;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #111;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #353535;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353535;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

this is the only way I've managed to get a separation between the div tags but the problem is that because I'm using the pressed class it fills the div with this style like this
http://i54.tinypic.com/uoux0.jpg
And i don't want it to be all filled. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your actual html. Could you paste it here or create a fiddle?

Comment: It's a little unclear what the problem is - have you a good understanding of css or are you struggling a bit?

Comment: It's not clear from looking at your screenshot which 2 divs you're trying to separate. Is it vertical space or horizontal space that you're trying to create? Will there be anything in between the 2 divs, or are you trying to create empty space?

Answer (score 0):

like other people said, you need to post the html or at least say what element do you want to add space to. This being said, I bet what you need is some clear:both somewhere, because that's the most common mistake on people starting with CSS